# Multiple many-to-may relation to the same object

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core 6.0 with .NET Core 6.0 and MySQL.
I have the following 2 Models:

```
public class User
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual List<ConsumerClub>? ConsumerClubs { get; set; }
}

public class ConsumerClub
{
  [Key]
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public virtual List<User>? Owners { get; set; }
  public virtual List<User>? Members { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, my ConsumerClub entity should have relations to the same User entity but for 2 different reasons - one is a list of owners, the other is a list of members.

I am failing to get it to work. The error I am getting is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'ConsumerClub.Owners' of type 'List<User>'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'
```

I then tried to create the relationship manually in OnodelCreating with the following changes:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ConsumerClub>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Owners)
                .WithMany(y => y.ConsumerClubs)
                ;

            modelBuilder.Entity<ConsumerClub>()
                .HasMany(x => x.Members)
                .WithMany(y => y.ConsumerClubs)
                ;
```

Then, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll: 'The skip navigation 'ConsumerClub.Members' doesn't have a foreign key associated with it. Every skip navigation must have a configured foreign key.'
```

Not sure how to set the Foreign Key or where...

Any help would be much appraciated.

Yaniv